# WebSQL collation in ORDERBY

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, collation, web-sql

Plase do someone know how to enforce specific collation in WEB SQL SELECT statement?
I'm interested in access insensitive case insensitive czech collation.

eg. running

```
SELECT * FROM employee ORDER BY name COLLATE CZECH
```

should work in Sqlite, but is not working in WebSQL implementation in Chrome.
I suppose ICU is completely missing?

Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

The WebSQL specification does not specify how SQLite is to be configured, so you cannot rely on any collation except the standard three `BINARY`, `NOCASE`, and `RTRIM` to be available.